# Force site to HTTPS except for some pages and Facebook crawler

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, https

There are a few similar questions to this, but none really covered everything I need to do and I'm a bit over my head!
I have an existing wordpress site. I want to force the home page and any *new* subpages to HTTPS but force *existing* subpages (about 20 of them) to HTTP. Reason being these subpages have long Facebook comment threads that I don't want to lose, and the canonical workarounds only retain likes/shares, not comments. To retain likes/shares, the Facebook crawler needs to be able to access the HTTP version of the home page.

So I need to work out the code for htaccess to enable:
 **1.** Force site generally to be HTTPS
 **2.** Force certain pages to be HTTP
 **3.** Allow the Facebook crawler to access the HTTP version of the home page (only).

Any help greatly appreciated.
EDIT added code I thought I'd try, but haven't:

```
RewriteEngine On 
# Go to https for all but existing subpages
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^ page1 | page2 | page3 $ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L] 

# Go to http for existing subpages 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^ page1 | page2 | page3 $ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Not sure where to put the Facebook crawler exception, nor whether I have the correct syntax to exclude pages, bearing in mind it's a wordpress site.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: Try it in a development environment and not much will be broken. Also add the code to your answer and format it properly otherwise it is very hard to read/understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the facebook crawler user agent, which [list here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler).

```
# Go to http for home page if Facebook Crawler
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^facebookexternalhit|Facebot
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^facebookexternalhit|Facebot
RewriteRule ^$ - [L]

# Go to https for all but existing subpages
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(page1|page2|page3)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

# Go to http for existing subpages 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(page1|page2|page3)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ben, that worked almost perfectly. The only change I needed to make was add a slash to each page name I wanted to redirect, as I got 404 errors without them. I assume because of the wordpress URL formatting. So the full working code is:

```
# Go to http for home page if Facebook Crawler
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^facebookexternalhit|Facebot
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^facebookexternalhit|Facebot
RewriteRule ^$ - [L]

# Go to https for all but existing subpages
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(page1/|page2/|page3/)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

# Go to http for existing subpages 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(page1/|page2/|page3/)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

I also added a og:url tag to the head of the home page, directing Facebook to crawl the HTTP version, maintaining the original like and share count.